# chrome Deceptive warning ahead is not changing after site have been reviewed

Tags: html

the site was blacklisted after which i brought the site down,fix the problem and asked for a review from Google. Google reviewed and certify that it is no more containing malware and i also used safebrowsing to scan it afterwards, it was passed as a safe site, but Chrome and Firefox still displaying the site as a deceptive site..what to do?

Comment: We have the same issue. Also on Android Chrome the warning is not being displayed, while on Windows Desktop it is. Have you been able to solve this?